# For loop Python- from Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, for-loop, matrix-multiplication

I am starting to code up in Python and I come from a Matlab background. I have a problem with a for loop that I am trying to do.

So this is my for loop from **Matlab**,

```matlab
ix = indoor(1);
idx = indoor(2)-indoor(1);
%Initialize X apply I.C
X = [ix;idx];
for k=(1:1:287)
    X(:,k+1) = Abest*X(:,k) + Bbest*outdoor(k+1) + B1best* (cbest4/cbest1);
end
```

In this code Abest is a 2x2 matrix, Bbest is a 2x1 matrix, outdoor is a 288x1 vector, B1best is a 2x1 matrix. The matricies are found from a function using the matrix expodential command. c4 and c1 are terms defined before, constants.

In **Python** I have been able to get the matrix exponential command to work in my function but I can't get that for loop to work.

```py
Xo = np.array([[ix],[idx]])
num1 = range(0,276)
for k in num1:
    Xo[:,k+1] = Ae*Xo[:,k] + Be*outdoor[k+1] + Be1*(c4/c1)
```

Again Ae,Be,Be1 are matrices of the same size just like the Matlab ones. Same thing for the outdoor vector.

I have tried everything I can think of to make it work... The only thing that worked for me was,

```py
Xo = np.zeros(())
#Initial COnditions
ix = np.array(indoor[0])
idx = np.array(indoor[1]-indoor[0])

Xo = np.array([[ix],[idx]])
#Range for the for loop
num1 = range(0,1) 
for k in num1:
    Xo = Ae*Xo[k] + Be*outdoor[k+1] + Be1*(c4/c1)
```

Now, this thing will work but only give me two points. If I change the range I get an error. I'm assuming this code works because my original Xo is just two states so k goes through those two states but that's not what I want.

If anyone could help me out that would be very helpful! If I'm making some code error, it's honestly because I'm not understanding the 'For loop' in python to well when it comes to data analysis and having it loop through the rows and increment the columns. Thank you for your time.

Upon Request here is my full code:

```
import scipy.io as sc
import math as m
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
from scipy.linalg import expm, sinm, cosm
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('datatemp.xlsx')

outdoor = np.array(df[['Outdoor']])
indoor = np.array(df[['Indoor']])

###########################. FUNCTION DEFINE. #################################################
#Progress bar
def progress(count, total, status=''):
    percents = round(100.0 * count / float(total), 1)
    sys.stdout.write(' %s%s ...%s\r' % ( percents, '%', status))
    sys.stdout.flush()
#Define Matrix for Model
def Matrixbuild(c1,c2,c3):
    A = np.array([[0,1],[-c3/c1,-c2/c1]])
    B = np.array([[0],[1/c1]])
    B1 = np.array([[1],[0]])
    C = np.zeros((2,2))
    D = np.zeros((2,2))

    F = np.array([[0,1,0,1],[-c3/c1,-c2/c1,1/c1,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]])
    R = np.array(expm(F))

    Ae = np.array([[R.item(0),R.item(1)],[R.item(4),R.item(5)]])
    Be = np.array([[R.item(2)],[R.item(6)]])
    Be1 = np.array([[R.item(3)],[R.item(7)]])
    return Ae,Be,Be1;

###########################. Data. ################################################# 
#USED FOR JUST TRYING WITHOUT ACTUAL DATA
# outdoor = np.array([5.8115,4.394,5.094,5.1123,5.1224])
# indoor = np.array([15.595,15.2429,15.0867,14.9982,14.8993])

###########################. Model Define. #################################################
Xo = np.zeros((2,288))
ix = np.array(indoor[0])
idx = np.array(indoor[1])

err_min = m.inf

c1spam = np.linspace(0.05,0.001,30)
c2spam = np.linspace(6.2,6.5,30)
c3spam = np.linspace(7.1,7.45,30)
totalspam = len(c1spam)*len(c2spam)*len(c3spam)
ind = 0

for c1 in c1spam:
            for c2 in c2spam:
                        for c3 in c3spam:
                                    c4 = 1.1
                                    #MatrixBuild Function
                                    result = Matrixbuild(c1,c2,c3)
                                    Ae,Be,Be1 = result
                                    Xo = np.array([ix,idx])

                                    Datarange = range(0,len(outdoor)-1,1)

                                    for k in Datarange:
                                            Xo[:,k+1] = np.matmul(Ae,Xo[:,k]) + np.matmul(Be,outdoor[k+1]) + Be1*(c4/c1)

                                    ind = ind + 1
                                    print(Xo)
                                    err = np.linalg.norm(Xo[0,range(0,287)]-indoor.T)
                                    if err<err_min:
                                        err_min = err
                                        cbest = np.array([[c1],[c2],[c3],[c4]])

                                    progress(ind,totalspam,status='Done')
# print(X)
# print(err)
# print(cbest)

###########################. Model with Cbest Values. #################################################
c1 = cbest[0]
c2 = cbest[1]
c3 = cbest[2]
result2 = Matrixbuild(c1,c2,c3)
AeBest,BeBest,Be1Best = result2
Xo = np.array([ix,idx])
Datarange = np.arange(0,len(outdoor)-1)
for k in Datarange:
            Xo[:,k+1] = np.matmul(AeBestb,Xo[:,k]) + np.matmul(BeBest,outdoor[k+1]) + Be1Best*(c4/c1)

err = np.linalg.norm(Xo[0,range(0,287)]-indoor.T)
print(cbest)
print(err)

###########################. Plots. #################################################
plt.figure(0)
time = np.linspace(1,2,2)
plt.scatter(time,X[0],s=15,c="blue")
plt.scatter(time,indoor[0:2],s=15,c="red")
plt.show()
```

And again my error occurs in the line with the for loop of 
for k in Datarange:

```
Xo[:,k+1] = np.matmul(Ae,Xo[k]) + np.matmul(Be,outdoor[k+1]) + Be1*(c4/c1)
```

I was trying to use np.matmul for matrix multiplication but even without it, it wasn't working.

If there are any other questions about my code please ask. Essentially I'm trying to find the best c1,c2,c3 coefficients that fit my data which is indoor temperature by using a basic second order constant coefficient model.

Comment: Could you provide an runnable example with dummy matrices? I will be helpful to understand what you want to do. `outdoor` could be only 3x1 for example

Comment: yes let me post that right now.

Comment: what's the error you got from python though?

Comment: The idea of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is that it can be copy/pasted to reproduce the error, it have to be as short as possible and include the (dummy) data... actually, writing it will help you (and people here) debug your code by isolating and simplifying the faulty part

Comment: @iamanigeeit error is IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1

Comment: See my updated answer... would have been much faster if you had posted the error in the original post, because it's immediately obvious that there's only 1 element in the array's 2nd axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So by reading into how python works a little more and allocation for arrays/matrices, I was able to find out how to do it. I needed to first allocate my 'Xo' value and then input the initial conditions in order for the For loop to work.

```
Xo = np.zeros((2,num2))         
Xo = np.asmatrix(Xo)
Xo[0,0] = ix
Xo[1,0] = idx
```

Also for the 'for loop', I called the range some value like this,

```
num1 = range(0,4)         
num2 = len(num1) + 1
```

This helped in order to calculate the total dimension of 'Xo', by calling it 'num2'. It was also defined like that because my 'For loop' went (k+1), this the dimension would grow larger, ex:

```
for k in num1:
        Xo[:,k+1] = Ae*Xo[:,k] + Be*outdoor[k+1] + Be1*(c4/c1)
```

But there it is! I figured it by comparing Matlab printouts to Python printouts and just trying to debug one line at a time. Now I have the same exact value print out in both goods, so it is time to start using the python code!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `Xo[:,k+1]` instead of `Xo(:,k+1)`? Python uses `[]` for slicing and indexing.

EDIT:

```
Xo = np.array([[ix],[idx]])
```

This creates a 1x1 array with 1 value: (ix, idx). I think you're looking for something like `Xo = np.zeros((ix, idx))`, which will give you an `ix`x`idx`  array initialized to zeros. If you don't need the zeros you can use `Xo = np.empty((ix, idx))`.

See the [docs on array creation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-creation.html#routines-array-creation).

Comment: Yes I have, sorry about that!